# How to use generics in builder pattern

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to use the builder pattern with generics but I don't know how to put it together. I would need some help and an explanation of the correct syntax. My code, and what I have tried.

```
public class LanguageMatcher<T, S> {

    // Code
    public final static class Builder<T, S> {

        // Code
    }
}

Usage (Error):

new LanguageMatcher<MyClass, YourClass>().Builder<MyClass, YourClass>()....
```

Comment: try this one: `new LanguageMatcher.Builder<MyClass, YourClass>();`

Comment: Funny to recieve a downvote on a question like this.'

Comment: @LuckyLuke not even SO is safe from trolls :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Type parameters are not inherited from outer class to static nested class.  So `Builder<T, S>` actually has a different `T` and `S` than `LanguageMatcher`.

So you don't need type parameters when attempting to qualify `Builder` with `LanguageMatcher`.  And because the `Builder` class is `static`, you don't need an instance of `LanguageMatcher` to instantiate a `Builder`:

```
LanguageMatcher.Builder<MyClass, YourClass> lm =
    new LanguageMatcher.Builder<MyClass, YourClass>();
```

Comment: One thing though: The LanguageMatcher class is generic because it implement a generic interface (not shown it earlier code). Do I need to deal with it in a special way? I mean, does T and S ever get set on LanguageMatcher<T, S> when I pass the builder object to the private constructor?

Comment: In your private constructor, you can take as a parameter a `Builder<T, S>`.  That way, you can create a `LanguageMatcher<MyClass, YourClass>` with a `Builder<MyClass, YourClass>`.  The Java compiler will infer the generic type parameters from the generic type parameters of the `Builder` object.

Comment: How can I learn more about the inferring of generic type parameters? I don't understand completly how and why.

Comment: There's [this part of the Java Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).